Inspector tells me that the electrician should have removed green screw from the panel
After an electrical inspection of my 3-unit multifamily building, the inspector told me that the electrician has made a mistake when he installed the new panel because he didn't remove the green screw.
I was wondering if we should put a different screw, perhaps a shorter screw that doesn't reach the metal body of the panel but still connects to the plastic? Or should we leave it empty?


is it a subpanel though?

You remove the ground screw entirely, and do not replace it with anything. Its only purpose is bonding the bar to the panel enclosure - it is not structural. If you look at the right-hand side of your panel, you'll see the exact same lug with no extra screw installed.
